# Why is $\nabla_X (\varphi Y)=\nabla_X(0\cdot\varphi Y)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, proof-explanation

When I read Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds : An Introduction to Curvature*, I am confused by the red line in the picture below. Why is $\nabla_X (\varphi Y)=\nabla_X(0\cdot\varphi Y)$?

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $Y$ vanishes on $U$. As $\varphi$ has support in $U$, $\varphi|_{M\setminus U} = 0$ and hence $\varphi Y \equiv 0$ on $M$. Therefore $\varphi Y = 0 = 0\cdot 0 = 0\cdot\varphi Y$.

Comment: I think it should be $\varphi Y$ ?

Comment: You are correct, that was a typo.

Comment: I still have a question, $\varphi$ is function and $Y$ is vector. So, $\varphi Y$ is vector,but $0\cdot 0$ is not vector. How to understand it ?

Comment: The first zero is the constant zero, the second is the zero vector field.